# QML: TextField horizontalAlignment not working for entered text in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: qt, qt4, qml

I'm a complete newbie to QML and QT, forgive me if this is a trivial question.

I'm using the following code to center-align the text in a TextField. This does work for the placeholder text, but the entered text isn't center-aligned.

Haven't been able to figure out what I'm missing. :(

```
TextField {
                id: pwdTF
                x: 52
                y: 190
                z: 6
                color: UbuntuColors.lightAubergine
                visible: true
                placeholderText: "<font color=\"LightSteelBlue\">Enter Password #</font>"
                horizontalAlignment: TextInput.AlignHCenter
                echoMode: TextInput.Password

            }
```

Comment: Works for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt 5.6, without event setting `width`.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `width` property. `horizontalAlignment` doesn't usually work without it.